# ARM template - Change in parameter not propagating in new deployment

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager

I have a initial deployment of a key vault by arm template with the following parameter:

```
"networkAcls": {
        "value": {
            "bypass": "AzureServices",
            "defaultAction": "Deny",
            "virtualNetworkRules": [],
            "ipRules": []
        }
      }
```

This configuration is set correctly but if I remove the parameter and rerun the same template deployment, the configuration is not removed in Azure. Is this by design? Is ARM only able to add new configurations and not remove in incremental mode?

Comment: its ommited y defaut if you dont specify it and was there before

Answer (score 0):

Based on the Azure resource manager documentation , When redeploying an existing resource in incremental mode, all properties are reapplied. The **properties aren't incrementally added**.

- A common misunderstanding is to think properties that aren't specified in the template are left unchanged.
- If you don't specify certain properties, Resource Manager interprets the deployment as overwriting those values.
- Properties that aren't included in the template are reset to the default values.

Here is the reference document to help you with [overview of Arm deployment types.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/deployment-modes#incremental-mode)